# Comparing four large lists of over 110,000 items

Tags: database, vba, excel

**Background:** I have four lists of product combinations for a project.  Each of every single product / customization combination available on our site. The four lists are for the four languages of our site.

Each text description of product / customization combination is separate in the database, and over the years, certain languages with certain product / customization combinations have been found to be missing from the database. (ie. no line for it in the SQL database so the site comes up with an error.)

**Problem:** I have four lists of over 110,000 items each with missing data, to simplify, let's say I have only ten products.

```
list 1 (L1): 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10
         L2: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9
         L3: 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10
         L4: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10
```

I now have these four lists in four columns in an Excel file. However, when I now attempt a 'For' loop through the first row all the way down to End(xlUp).row... it freezes after about 6,000 entries. My CPU at 99%, Excel and surprisingly memory still about 1 GB free (out of 4 GB).

I tried to find other solutions here on Stack Overflow, and it led me to a function that compared two variants that had the entire columns inside them. It was a `For each x in arr` type methodology. This also proved non-useful, as my computer froze about 10,000 entries into it.

**Goal:**  My goal, in the example I gave, is to have four smaller lists of the missing entries for each language. In the example:

```
L1: 4, 9
L2: 7
L3: 2, 7
L4: 7
```

Two major problems I am clueless on:

1. How do I efficiently compare all four lists and make sure my computer doesn't crash?
2. How do I efficiently find an entry like `7` in my example?

(I would assume that comparing every list to every other list till eventually I compare L1 with one of the others to find `7` missing from most of them is not efficient.)

**Solution:**  I picked the answer below and slightly modified his code.

My computer was freezing during the loops with over 440,000 loops in them, and I found out that by placing a ***DoEvents*** within the loop, this command gives Excel 'some air to breathe'. When it runs this ***DoEvents***, it performs any backed up tasks besides the currently running macro, thus allowing Excel files to be edited during the macro running.

Also, at the end, when the list of missing items is being written, if the list just checked had nothing missing, there was an error, so I just used ***On Error resume next*** for it just in case.

```
Dim MyAr As Variant

    Sub Sample()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim lRow As Long, n As Long, r As Long, j As Long
        Dim Col As New Collection
        Dim itm
        Dim aCell As Range
        Dim FinalList() As String

        '~~> Let's say this sheet has the 4 lists in Col A to D
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

        With ws
            '~~> Find the last Row in Col A to D which has data
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                lRow = .Range("A:D").Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=.Range("A1"), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
            Else
                lRow = 1
            End If

            '~~> Create a unique list
            Dim z As Variant
            z = 0
            For Each aCell In .Range("A1:D" & lRow)
                If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Col.Add aCell.Text, CStr(aCell.Text)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End If
                z = z + 1
                Debug.Print z
                DoEvents
            Next

            '~~> Output Column Say in Col J
            r = 10

            '~~> Loop through the list to match
            For j = 1 To 4
                Set aCell = .Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(lRow, j))
                MyAr = aCell.Value

                z = 0
                For Each itm In Col
                    If ItemExist(itm) = False Then
                        ReDim Preserve FinalList(n)
                        FinalList(n) = itm
                        n = n + 1
                    End If
                    z = z + 1
                    Debug.Print z
                    DoEvents
                Next

                '~~> Output The results
                .Cells(1, r).Value = "Missing List in List" & j

                On Error Resume Next

                .Cells(2, r).Resize(UBound(FinalList) + 1, 1).Value = _
                Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(FinalList)

                On Error GoTo 0

                r = r + 1

                Erase FinalList
                n = 0
            Next
        End With

    End Sub

    Function ItemExist(sVal As Variant) As Boolean
        Dim i As Long

        For i = 0 To UBound(MyAr) - 1
            If sVal = MyAr(i + 1, 1) Then
                ItemExist = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic that you are trying to follow here for the number 7. Are you looking for a number which is not on all 4 list? Or a number which is in the other 3 list but not in the 1st list?

Comment: Siddharth - I have a list of 110,000 entries, so unlike 10, it is difficult to know how many actual entries there exist in the database from my incomplete lists. If my lists were 1,2,3 - 4,5,6 - 7,8,9 -10,11,12. it may look like I only have 3 entries, but in actuality I have 12 entries and each list is missing 9 entries each. If I compare L2 to L3, I will not know the existence of 7 because both lists are missing it. I am saying that I do not know an efficient way to do this except for checking every list with every other list. This seems inefficient and it would seem like there is better way.

Comment: Is it an option to export the (largish) amount of data to a file and process it with a language more conducive to this task?

Comment: You could make one unique list from all 4 lists and then check it with your database. If you use Array, then I don't see this taking lot of time...

Comment: GreenAsJade - The only programming language I am at all literate in is VBA as it pertains to Excel Macros. What would you recommend using? I will try to study up on it.

Comment: If I show you how to create one unique list quickly, would that help?

Comment: Siddharth - Could you explain this in further detail? Would I just create a variant like "arr" and then do something like "Set arr = Range("A1:A440000").Value"? What would I do with the combined list after this?

Comment: Once you get the unique list in say Col A then you match it with the database to check which one is missing.

Comment: Siddharth - Also, don't forget in the end I would like to know which entries are missing from each individual list. If you could help me through until that end, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you confirm two things for me. `1` Which Excel version are you using. `2` Is it ok if I import the data from SQL database into Excel.

Comment: Siddharth - Ok, is this what you mean?

1. combine the 4 lists into a list on Column A.

2. find unique entries for list on column A.

3. Compare list on column A to the 4 original lists and note any time an entry can not be found on the list.

4. Write out the entries not found into 4 new lists.

Am I correct? If this is what you suggest, this is something I have tried but my excel froze my computer.

Comment: 1. Excel 2010 2. I have asked the system admin, but they said they don't have any read-only servers for queries, so any large queries will interfere with customer bandwidth, and may bring the servers down.

Comment: So how were you planning to compare the unique list with the database?

Comment: They told me to give them a list of the missing entries for each language, and they would add the entries into the database. I am asking this question so I could find the missing entries for them. I asked them to do it, but they said "no one is fluent enough in Excel VBA here, sorry"

Comment: I wish this could be moved to chat. Seems like you need two more upvotes to chat. Hope someone upvotes you soon.

Comment: The 4 lists I have is every possible product number in the database... but they are missing entries from each other. This means if I combine all 4 lists and only take the unique entries, this will be the product numbers of the whole database. Everything I need is on my excel file.

Comment: Ok then in short, you want the missing entries in List1 which could be in the other lists... correct? And same for the other lists.

Comment: @Sidharth Rout Yes I want the missing entries in List1 that are in other lists, but not in List1. I will then make a small list of those "missing numbers" for each list (total of 4)

Comment: Got it. :) Already writing a code... Gimme few minutes

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you so much. I will try the code when I go back in tomorrow morning. Any explanations with it will help. Thank you.

Comment: This will take some time bacuse I will be testing it with at least 200k data

Comment: If you have this information in database then SQL seems like the obvious approach to this problem. What kind of database is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok try this for me. This doesn't use any formulas and hence will be easy on Excel. Everything is performed in memory.

**Logic:**

1. Store the values from all 4 list in 1 unique list
2. Store each column in an array in a loop
3. Match Unique list with array to check for missing values.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyAr As Variant

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, n As Long, r As Long, j As Long
    Dim Col As New Collection
    Dim itm
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim FinalList() As String

    '~~> Let's say this sheet has the 4 lists in Col A to D
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last Row in Col A to D which has data
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Range("A:D").Find(What:="*", _
                   After:=.Range("A1"), _
                   Lookat:=xlPart, _
                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                   MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        '~~> Create a unique list
        For Each aCell In .Range("A1:D" & lRow)
            If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Col.Add aCell.Value, CStr(aCell.Value)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next

        '~~> Output Column Say in Col J
        r = 10

        '~~> Loop through the list to match
        For j = 1 To 4
            Set aCell = .Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(lRow, j))
            MyAr = aCell.Value

            For Each itm In Col
                If ItemExist(itm) = False Then
                    ReDim Preserve FinalList(n)
                    FinalList(n) = itm
                    n = n + 1
                End If
            Next

            '~~> Output The results
            .Cells(1, r).Value = "Missing List in List" & j
            .Cells(2, r).Resize(UBound(FinalList) + 1, 1).Value = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(FinalList)

            r = r + 1

            Erase FinalList
            n = 0
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function ItemExist(sVal As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(MyAr) - 1
        If sVal = MyAr(i + 1, 1) Then
            ItemExist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**ScreenShot:**

Let's say you list looks like this

[image]

When you run the code, the output will be generated in Col J onwards

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful. May I ask one question. My 4 lists are slightly different numbers of entries (your example was "3" "3" "3" "3", but my lists are like: "110,478" "110,463" "110,493" "110,482" for number of entries.) Would this still work? I don't understand what your ".Find("*"...=FALSE).Row" is doing, but if find is looking for the first blank, won't it find the last row of the shortest list? Thank you.

Comment: It is trying to find the last row in the column A-D. I could have done it for individual columns but then that would increase the lines of the code. Also `If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then` takes care of the blank cells in the end. I have not tested with such a long list. Let me do that later tonight and I will post back.

Comment: Also, I have a question. Some of my product numbers start with trailing 0s. (ie. "000063782023") So I must store all of my product numbers as strings to make sure the 0s at the beginning are maintained. Item # 0001 and # 001 are two different items... Yes, I know... it makes me pull my hair out. Question: Will my numbers be ok with your code?

Comment: For that you will have to change `Col.Add aCell.Value, CStr(aCell.Value)` to `Col.Add aCell.Text, CStr(aCell.Text)`

Comment: On a personal note, I think my code will also slow down for such huge lists (each 100k). I might use Access or VB.Net to sort this out...

Comment: I used MATCH from the other answer, and it kept freezing. Then I tried your macro, and it froze about 6,000 entries into Col.Add. My solution was I added the line "DoEvents" right before the Next in the For loop. This apparently allows excel to perform other actions that are awaiting to be processed and prevents freezes. It took about 2.5 hours to run. Also, one list had all items, and when it went to write the missing items from FinalList, it gave me an error. I will edit my question with used code and final solution and results. I will elect you as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your computer is struggling to cope with all four lists at once then one at a time may be expedient. You could do as @Sid suggested, create a comprehensive list of one instance of all possible values then compare that one language at a time with a formula such as `=IF(MATCH(A1,C:C,0)>0,"",)` copied down to suit, where ColumnA would be your master list and C etc each individual language's list. `#N/A` would indicate which value in ColumnA is missing from ColumnC (etc).

Comment: These 4 lists needs to be finally matched with the SQL database entries

Comment: @pnuts you are correct, my final goal is to get 4 small lists of the missing entries in each list. Once I have these smaller lists, the database INSERT commands will be handled by IT. Thank you.

Comment: +1 Oh, If you have already done it then you might want to post that solution. I won't bother then working on the code :)

Comment: @pnuts Thanks a lot, I will try it out tomorrow. Also, today I tried doing a normal function using COUNTIF, but when pulling it down to 110,000 the excel started to slow down to snails pace and eventually stopped responding. I have Windows 7, Core i3 3270M 2 cores 4 threads at 2.5 GHz with 4GB of RAM. I hope this MATCH function is less resource intensive.